# iPad as WiFi router

Tags: ios, ipad, wifi

I've been tasked with getting an iPad to talk to an external device wirelessly on the cheap. I tried the Bluetooth route (not LE - need higher data transfer rate), but we're not willing to go through MFi.

So now I'm looking at WiFi. It may be possible to configure my external device to act as a WiFi router, but it may be easier to get the iPad to act as the router. That's what I'm trying to figure out here.

So I've thought of two possibilities, neither of which I could find any answers for on Google or within SO. Does anyone know the answer to any of these?

- Is it possible to have the iPad act as a WiFi router such that other devices connect to the iPad and can communicate with an app on the iPad?
- When built-in tethering is active on the iPad, does the iPad have an IP address that is visible to any device connected to the iPad's WiFi hotspot?
- When built-in tethering is active of the iPad, is there a way for the iPad to get notified of connections made to the hotspot and get the IP addresses of those devices?

A little more specifically, I need a way for a device to wirelessly communicate with an app on the iPad. I've already gone through the Bluetooth route and I'm hoping for a WiFi answer.

Thank you.

Comment: You can have the iPad act as a proxy: https://github.com/tcurdt/iProxy/wiki/ , but I'm not sure that services what you want here. Have you looked at Bonjour discovery of the iPad and these other devices? They need to be on the same network, but it allows for direct discovery and communication between them over  WiFi.

Comment: @BradLarson The thing about that is I need the iPad and the external device to connect directly - I can't rely on a separate network. Also, I need the app to be publishable on the App Store. Requiring paid tethering will be fine if there's no better option.

Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interest of not leaving a question open, I'll answer with what I've found:

No

As far as I've been able to tell in my research and experimentation, there is no way to do what I was hoping for. Thank you to Brad Larson for doing his best to give me options.